# Asp.Net 4.0 MVC 3: Post html code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

When posting textbox content which contains html code, I get an error regarding possible dangerous content. I read how to configure the old 2.0 behaviour, but it does not work for me and I would prefer to have a clean solution. I'm probably not the only person which needs to post html, so I wonder that I could not found a solution for disabling this behaviour. Any hint what's the correct way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

For your input model, you can define:

```
public class FormViewModel
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Where `Content` is your appropriate field:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Content)
```

Comment: Lol, maybe you should? It helps encapsulate all of your input parameters into a structured model, and gives you the benefits of model binding and model validation...

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the Validate Input attribute to the controller method?

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

I think you only need these in your web.config if using web forms as well as mvc, but might be worth trying.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: the web.confix modification is not needed in MVC 3

Comment: It's not good to false all validation for just one field, I prefer Matthew abbot answer.